# MacBook screen turns off when setting brightness one notch below maximum

Tags: macbook-pro, display

When I press the lower brightness key (F1) on my MacBook the screen turns off (pitch black). When I raise the brightness back (F2) everything is fine again. This only started happening recently with this machine and I can't think of anything that I've changed that could have caused this.

- macOS Sierra 10.12.4
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)

Comment: This is a feature, not a problem. You probably didn't notice it before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Restarting the computer resolved this. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Restarting my computer also worked

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I would try is resetting your NVRAM.

**Resetting the NVRAM**

Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). Here’s how to reset the NVRAM on your model:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys. You have to make sure you press these keys **before** the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).